# VectorKit/OpenGL crashes in MKMapView since iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, mapkit

I can see from the Crashlytics that some of my app users are getting the following crashes. I have never seen these myself and don't know how to reproduce them as they don't have my code in the stack trace. I have read about OpenGL that some crashes are possible when trying to update the surface while the app is in the background. Not sure if that is the case here because the crashes didn't occur before iOS 9.

I have several annotations on the map, custom MKAnnotationView derived views, some custom overlays and a MKTileOverlay derived tile source. The map handling code and overlays are Objective-C, but my app has also some Swift code.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be the reason for the crashes?

1)

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.maps.geogl.renderQueue
0  VectorKit                      0x18c82a894 ___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke_2 + 876
1  VectorKit                      0x18c82a47c ___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke + 212
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x182625630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1826255f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x182631634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
```

2)

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.mapdisplay.stylesheetLoadQueue
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ec2a90 dispatch_async + 76
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ec2a88 dispatch_async + 68
2  VectorKit                      0x18df501c4 std::__1::__function::__func<-[VKTileSetBackedTileSource setStyleManager:]::$_0, std::__1::allocator<-[VKTileSetBackedTileSource setStyleManager:]::$_0>, void (std::__1::shared_ptr<gss::StyleManager>, bool)>::operator()(std::__1::shared_ptr<gss::StyleManager>&&, bool&&) + 176
3  VectorKit                      0x18e11533c std::__1::__function::__func<gss::StyleManager::addFinishedDecodingGlobalPropertiesCallback(std::__1::function<void (std::__1::shared_ptr<gss::StyleManager>, bool)>)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<gss::StyleManager::addFinishedDecodingGlobalPropertiesCallback(std::__1::function<void (std::__1::shared_ptr<gss::StyleManager>, bool)>)::$_0>, void (bool)>::operator()(bool&&) + 88
4  VectorKit                      0x18e10c248 ___ZN3gss10StyleSheet43addFinishedDecodingGlobalPropertiesCallbackENSt3__18functionIFvbEEE_block_invoke + 56
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ec1630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ec15f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ecd634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ec50f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x183ecf504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x183ecf224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1840d5470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1840d5020 start_wqthread + 4
```

3)

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x23f6a2eb __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x23736dff objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x23f69d6d -[NSException name]
3  VectorKit                      0x2c923af9 -[VKRasterOverlayTileSource _queueDraw:]
4  VectorKit                      0x2c5e74ad -[VKTileSource fetchTileForKey:]
5  VectorKit                      0x2c7c512d -[VKTileProvider dirtyTilesFromTileSource:]
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x23b07dd7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x23b07dc3 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x23b0c671 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
9  CoreFoundation                 0x23f2cfc5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x23f2b4bf __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x23e7dbb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 CoreFoundation                 0x23e7d9ad CFRunLoopRunInMode
13 GraphicsServices               0x250f7af9 GSEventRunModal
14 UIKit                          0x28169fb5 UIApplicationMain
15 MyApp                          0x252d44 main (main.swift:12)
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x23b30873 (Missing)
```

Comment: Somewhere I found that this may happen when the user is trying to comeback to the application via the top link on iOS which says "Back to AppName".

Comment: A similar crashlog from my app is following:

Answer (score 0):

1. A similar crashlog from my app as the following. From the thread name "com.apple.maps.geogl.renderQueue", I guess that is related with usage of the MapKit framework.
2. I found the "gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient" in the Technical QA: 
   "How to fix OpenGL ES application crashes when moving to the background" 
   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1766/_index.html

Crashed: com.apple.maps.geogl.renderQueue
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000001

```
0  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x190a45f08 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient
1  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x190a46ec4 gpusSubmitDataBuffers
2  VectorKit                      0x18c7d1a0c ___ZN3ggl10GLRenderer5frameEPNS_12RenderTargetEPNS_11RenderQueueE_block_invoke + 212
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ec94bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ec947c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ed54c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x181eccf80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ed7390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ed9934 _dispatch_worker_thread + 124
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1820e3b28 _pthread_body + 156
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1820e3a8c _pthread_body + 154
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1820e1028 thread_start + 4
```